# How to append values from txt file? Python3

Tags: python-3.x, file, class, append

I have to classes where each of them are in separate py.files

```
class Song(object):

    def __init__(self, tittel, artist):

        #Instanse variabler

        self._tittel = tittel

        self._artist = artist
```

Then another py.file:

```
from song import Song

class Playlist:
    def __init__(self, listName):
        self._songs = []
        self._name = listName

    def lesFraFil(self, file):
        tittel = self._tittel
        artist = self._artist


        with open("songs.txt", "r") as f:
            contents = f.readlines()
            for line in contents:
                info = line.strip().split(';') #contains ";" between title and artist
                tittel = info[0]
                artist = info[1]
            self._songs.append(tittel,artist)
```

Then when I try to append, I get this error:

```
    tittel = self._tittel
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_tittel'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you calling lesFraFil anywhere? Also, in that method self doesn't have a `_tittel` attribute. It only has `_songs` and `_name`

Comment: Yes, I do call it. I didnt bring it here. 
But if I import from song , shouldn't i get _tittel in this file? Like if inherit it?

Comment: Playlist isn't inheriting from Song. And `self._songs` is just a list. `lesFraFil` is a method on the `Playlist` object, so it's `self` can only access `Playlist` attributes (`_songs` and `_name`).

Comment: Ok, now I did like this: 
class Spilleliste:
    def __init__(self, listName):
        self._songs = []
        self._name = listName


    def lesFraFil(self, file):
        
        
        filename = open("musikk.txt", "r")
            
        filecontents = filename.readlines()
        for line in filecontents:
            info = line.strip().split(';')
            self._songs.append(info)


I still get this error: tittel AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_songs'